# How is the ideal plenum volume, shape and take off configuration determined?

Tags: hvac, ducts

I'm hoping to learn some general rules for plenums coming directly off equipment in typical single family HVAC.  Most of all, I'm curious if it is good design to keep the plenum only large enough to connect branch ducts, or if there are reasons (perhaps fluid dynamics because of the turn, or if air needs to slow down, mixing, or I don't know what) that having a larger volume plenum is advantageous.

There obviously be an impact to the velocity of the air and the pressure with an enlarged plenum coming off the equipment.... is this something typical or do most systems try to keep the plenum the size of the outlet from the blower?

For example, I've learned that after a sharp turn, especially where there is no throat and no turning vanes, that airflow might need some distance to recover and normalize.  This seems quite pertinent to a vertical stack with a roof in close proximity, where an immediately change to horizontal direction(s) is required.  So should a plenum extend a foot or two just for this purpose?  And then are there any benefits or penalties to having a larger volume space for take offs to the branch ducts?

Another example -- I was watching a youtube video with horizontal equipment where the installer replaced what appeared to be an intentionally enlarged plenum with all take offs on the far end, away from the equipment. He installed a smaller plenum sized to the opening from the blower.  What would be the impact of such a change?

Is the goal to keep the pressure and velocity as high as possible, or is what comes off of a typical air handler so high that you need to let things expand, slow down and mix a bit?

Are there some general guidelines that can be discussed before jumping into specifics, calculations and sizing the whole system?  I can find very little introductory information about how a plenum should be shaped and placement of take offs.

THanks in advance for any knowledge you can impart!

Comment: Generally speaking, you want to keep the pressure loss and resulting required velocities as *low* as possible.  Also, have you looked into ACCA Manual D at all, as well as the known issues with flex duct causing pressure loss?

Comment: I'm just starting to scratch the surface.  I have heard that for flex that you need one size higher than metal to account for friction.  This question is focused on the plenum/main distribution box so are you referring to pressure loss there?  If so, then transitioning to a larger volume segment at the exit to the air handler would drop the pressure I guess, so that is bad? Best to keep the plenum pressure and velocity as high as possible?

Comment: Mostly, that "ductopus" setups are pretty much unrescuable due to their reliance on flex

Comment: Yep, I got that.  I'm interested in talking about plenums and what the goal is immediately upon air exiting the equipment.

Comment: I can imagine a chapter or two in a book covering this, or even a couple of weeks in a classroom. This seems far too broad to be covered here.

Comment: Heat loss and heat gain are calculated for each room and then duct sizes are determined for each room.

Comment: Great question.   I hate the vote to close this stuff since it's literally the most useful type of content.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I did watch a long youtube presentation that had some screen shots from ACCA Manual D last night and yep that is the kind of thing I am after.  Unfortunately it costs $50 for even a used copy of that manual.

Comment: @CA_Tallguy -- [Allison Bailes' duct design tutorial](https://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/basic-principles-duct-design/) is probably the best starting point (search their blog for "duct design" if you want the remaining parts of it

Answer (score 1):

There is a science to sizing ductwork.  And I'm no expert at this at all, **I just know what I don't know.**  Here is a link that might be useful: https://www.oceanhvac.com/ductulator/

You need to get this right the first time...there are no "rules of thumb", there are proven methods to size the ductwork properly.  fixing it after installation would be a total PITA.

Hopefully others with more knowledge than me will chime in.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I know this is a science and there are lots of calculations and measurements needed to actually do it.  Right now I am only interested in theory and even the fluid dynamics, placement of the take offs, shape of the plenum, etc.  For a vertical air handler with little clearance above, a sharp turn, tee or radial distribution is required there and I'm interested in how this is normally handled and if there are best practices in this transition and for the sizing of the plenum/manifold box.